# why does my webscraper fail to scrape data from Puma website?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing a script to scrape product details from Puma's official website- https://in.puma.com/in/en/home

The script runs without any errors as such. However, it just does not scrape details and returns empty values. I was previously working with xpaths but I made changes to my code and have taken class names for scraping data like product price,title,colors.
here's my code:

```
def puma_product_scraper():
    titles = []
    prices = []
    p_colors = []
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('start-maximized')
    options.add_argument("window-size=1200x600")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
    browser.get("https://in.puma.com/in/en/search?q=running&originalphrase=running")
    browser.implicitly_wait(10)

    # Begin scraping elements

    # browser.find_element_by_class_name('btn').click()
    product_cards_container = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "product-grid-container")
    product_cards = product_cards_container.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-6")
    for card in product_cards:
        title = card.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "product-tile-info-text")
        colors = card.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "product-tile-swatch-container")
        price = card.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "product-tile-price-new product-tile__price--new")
        titles.append(title.text)
        p_colors.append(colors.text)
        prices.append(price.text)

    # Storing scraped content
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Product Name': titles, 'Price': prices, 'Colors': p_colors})
    df.to_csv('PUMA_Scraping.csv', index=False)
    df.head()
    print('Total items related to running on Puma:', len(titles))
```

Here's the output that I get:

```
Total items related to running on Puma: 0
```

If there are problems related to class names, then It shouldve displayed an error message, but I have not recieved any messages as such? Where is the problem exactly? please help.

**EDIT**:
As @Joran suggested applied variations for find_element.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
    # browser.find_element_by_class_name('btn').click()
    product_cards_container = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "product-grid-container")))
```

still did not work.

Comment: right  after your implicit_wait(10) add `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` then when you hit your new breakpoint ... try executing variations of browser.wait_for... and browser.find_element

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: @cruisepandey a list of titles and prices for eg: [adidas running shoes, adidas running shoes1,....] [Rs 4000, Rs 3200,....] should be saved to my dataframe and subsequently to my csv file.  Since  the values are not saving into the lists I  get an empty dataframe and an empty CSV file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to go ahead with CSS_SELECTOR in this case, I have extracted titles same way you can achieve price also.

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Inc\\Desktop\\Selenium+Python\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://in.puma.com/in/en/search?q=running&originalphrase=running")

titles = []
prices = []
p_colors = []
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-grid-container')))
product_cards = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.row.product-grid.no-gutters div[data-grid-tile-wrapper]")
titles = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.product-tile-title.product-tile__title.pdp-link.line-item-limited")
for title in titles:
    print(title.text)
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, however made made you select with a css_selector?? why wasn't it working with the class name? Is there a specific reason?

Comment: Well it should work with any locator as long as that locator represent all elements. both class name and css selector are reliable. There's not much performance hit. But be careful with Xpath for cross browser testing.